# Default character set for PDO::quote

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo, character-encoding

The PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) says:

> The character set must be set either on the server level, or within
>   the database connection itself (depending on the driver) for it to
>   affect PDO::quote(). See the driver-specific documentation for more
>   information.

However, if you follow the link and read the driver-specific documentation, there isn't any information about. Where can I find detailed information about?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more informatiion for MySQL:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php